# Determine the framework used from a website source dump

Tags: php

I don't know if this is the right place to ask a question like this, but it is programming related, so here goes.

I was given a zip file containing the entire source data for a website, including the scripts used to create the database backing it. I know that the site was built using a PHP-based framework, but not which one. I was asked to gain some basic familiarity with the structure of the site, and be able to make at least small changes to the UI.

The problem I have is that I don't recognize the framework used, although I'm pretty sure that the site was built using one. I know it isn't Zend, but that's about it.

The question is, what would you look for from the source in order to determine the technology used to create a site, given the product?

Comment: Checkout [Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/) and [BuiltWith](https://builtwith.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following to attempt to determine the framework:

1) Check the folder structure against the more known frameworks

2) Check for hints in the HTTP response headers, comments in source files, HTML output,  license and so on.

Sometimes the site may not be built with a known framework, though it may look like it is using one.

Comment: Could you give some example frameworks that I could try this with? Being very new to PHP, I don't even know that...

Comment: Cake, Symfony and CodeIgniter are some of the popular ones. I'd start with those.

Comment: Based on the lack of nice directory structures, (even the CSS files are in the root directory, along with 90+ php files, some html files, some script files, etc) I'm going to lean toward fully home-grown development with no framework base. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Get the website/application online and make use of services like http://builtwith.com which gives you an insight about common frameworks, webservers, etc.

Comment: yeah, this one works too.  I tried this one too.